# Firebase JobScheduling in the cloud | How to use the Server SDK for JobScheduling

Tags: java, android, firebase, jobs, gcm-network-manager

I've seen lots of APIs for Job Scheduling, if I may mention:

- `AlarmManager`
- `JobScheduler`
- `JobSchedulerCompat`
- `GCMNetworkManager`

And what I'm trying to do is, a user sets a date along with a campaign, he saved it in Firebase, and when that date comes, that created object gets deleted. I've seen something similar with Parse, but as you might know, it's shutting down and I'm storing my data in Firebase anyways.

However, **`AlarmManager`** surely doesn't do the task in the **cloud** (*The service doesn't run on the device, but in the cloud.*)

**`JobScheduler`** is not available for pre-lollipop.

**`JobSchedulerCompat`** is deprecated "*There's no guarantee this won't explode your device or drain your battery*" and I don't think it runs in the cloud anyways.

And I'm not sure about `GCMNetworkManager`. Does it run in the cloud or is it on the device? **Tough example:** If every single user who uses my app has his device shut down, will the task still be completed?

---

**Long question short:** Does `GCMNetworkManager` run in the cloud? If not, what alternatives do I have?

---

**Edit:** @qbix's answer gave me a hint, but I still cannot understand anything from that link. If anyone answers my question along with an example, he will be awarded the bounty. This includes @qbix.

Comment: Wish I had more time to work on this.  Have you seen the [Quick Start](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-java/tree/master/database) project?  It will be helpful if you don't get a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `GCMNetworkManager` does not run in the cloud.  It runs on the device just like the other schedulers you listed.

If I understand your requirements correctly, you should look into the [Firebase Server SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start).  You would create a server task with limited privileges to access the appropriate sections of your database.  It would perform the needed database maintenance for all users on a periodic basis.

Comment: the firebase server SDK looks good, but it looks like a database itself. Would I have to migrate my whole app to that? Or is there just some code to do a task? And I didn't find any code for saving a task, or am I wrong? Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: I'm going to award you a total of 50 reputation if you make you provide me with an example and answer my questions in the previous comment.